# How can I get my computer to allow hibernate again?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hibernate

My computer used to allow me to hibernate.  Then my System Admins installed full disk encryption and it does not give me the option now.

I know it is not a domain restriction because two of my co-workers (who have almost the exact same computer as me) did not have hibernate disabled after they got full disk encryption installed.

I have tried the obvious `powercfg.exe /hibernate on` and I don't see a hibernate option after doing that.

Is there something else I can do?  Some deeper setting I can change to flip the switch and turn this back on?

I am running x64 Windows 7 Professional.  I have a Dell Laptop (Precision M6500).

Comment: Which form of full-disk encryption is it?  BitLocker? TrueCrypt?

Comment: @techie - Check Point http://www.checkpoint.com/products/full-disk-encryption/index.html

Answer (score 2):

According to the [release notes](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doShowproductpage&productTab=documents&product=377), it could very well be the version of CheckPoint FDE being used.

For example:

[New in 7.4 HFA R3](http://downloads.checkpoint.com/dc/download.htm?ID=11134):

> - Hibernation on 64-bit machines is now supported
>
> Known Limitations in this version:
>
> 00515071 - It is not possible to hibernate a Windows 7 computer if the system reserve partition or 
>   the active partition is only boot protected and not encrypted.

[Issues Resolved in v7.4.4](http://downloads.checkpoint.com/dc/download.htm?ID=12004):

> 00515071 - It was not possible to hibernate a Windows 7 computer if the
>   system reserve partition or the active partition was only boot
>   protected and not encrypted.

[Known Limitations in version v7.4.5](http://downloads.checkpoint.com/dc/download.htm?ID=12385):

> 00516415 - Hibernation does not work on a 3DES encrypted machine.

So everything before v7.4 didn't support Hibernation on a 64-bit machine, and even the version(s) after still had some troubles if the System Reserved partition that Windows 7 makes for potential BitLocker use exists, or if 3DES was used as the encryption method.

You'll probably have to discuss it with the company's SysAdmins.

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid sleep might be enabled. You can disabled it in the power options.

1. Open Start menu
2. Type in the search `pow opt` (Power Options should be the top result.)
3. Click `Change plan settings` to the right of the currently selected power plan (the radio button on the left indicates that)
4. Click `Change advanced power settings`
5. In the modal dialog, expand `Sleep` then expand `Allow hybrid sleep`
6. Click `On battery` and/or `Plugged in`
7. Click `On` and change it to `Off`
8. Close the dialog by clicking `OK`
9. Check the start menu's shutdown options

Comment: There is no "Allow hybrid sleep" option...

Comment: That's very odd. Try the [MSFT FAQ on sleep & hibernation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions).